# Add to an array using spread operators - React/JS

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have a dropdown in which I would like to use to add items to an array.
Currently it functions that if you click, it will add to the array, however I want to ADD to the array, using the ...prevState + NEW item.
This will result in an array like

```
[
 option: "Additional leave",
option: "Pay",
option: "Holidays",

]
```

As you add more items.

How would you write this to {...spread} the state, and then ADD?

Currently i'm holding the state in two ways, I think this is wrong: first is what's been selected, second holding final list (IS GOAL)

```
    const [selectedBenefits1, setselectedBenefits1] = useState('')
    const [finalBenefits, setFinalBenefits] = useState([])
```

My component is:

````
 <Dropdown_Content>

                {interviewStageSelection.map((option, prev) => (
                    <Dropdown_Item 
                        key={option}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                        setselectedBenefits1(option)
                        setisActive(!isActive)
                        setFinalBenefits(prev=>({...finalBenefits, option}))
                        // setisActive(false)
                        // updateInterview1(dispatch, option)
                    }}
                    >
                      <Typography variant="subtitle5" color="black" sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "white" } }}>{option}</Typography>
                    </Dropdown_Item>
                ))}
            </Dropdown_Content>
```


I believe the main issue is:

```
setFinalBenefits(prev=>({...finalBenefits, option}))
```

How would you write this?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `option` is a string,

```
setFinalBenefits(prevFinalBenefits => [ // note that this is a square bracket (array), instead of a curly bracket (object)
    ...prevFinalBenefits, // why not using the prev value
    { option } // shorthand of { option: option }
]);
```

Comment: Thankyou kind sir for the answer! Excellent. How would you ensure no duplicate entries are allowed?

Comment: You may better of using Set for that case. No duplication is a property of Set, while you need to do an O(n) scan to check whether there are duplications in an array.